# CSS Height in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I am working on a [site](http://www.centredesantementis.com/contact-us) and I have to align the bottom of the right box (Affiliation) with the bottom of the right box (Contact Us).

The problem is, I can make it work in Chrome, IE and Mozilla and even Safari on Windows, but NOT when it is Safari on Mac. I don't have Mac but I am using Adobe BrowserLab to see how it is (and the client says it doesn't work :P)

I've tried several codes / CSS including @media but still no luck (if you see the code / layout is changing then it may be me working on it).

Both the markup and CSS is simple and standard one, just need help to make it work in major browsers, Chrome, Firefox, (modern)IE, and Safari on Mac.

Current code:

```
#bottom-aff{
    display:inline;
    height: 145px !important;
}
```

but as I said, I am working on it.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not the most elegant solution, but it seems to work:

```
#contentleft {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.postarea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

It basically lets the right sidebar decide the height of #content, and then forces the left content to expand to fill the remaining space. Content might get cut off if the left column is taller than the right sidebar.

Comment: Yup, it works! Thanks buddy :) Never thought of playing with the content area to resolve this issue and was too concentrated in the sidebar / widget. I use WordPress body class to target just this page and apply your code, all work! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use max-height,min-height property.